# Ajax.BeginForm says action doesn’t exists, however it does

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, resharper

I am working with AJAX Helper method in one my applications, things were all good and right but suddenly am facing this strange problem i.e. in view

```
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Feedback", "User", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore, HttpMethod = "POST", OnFailure = "searchFailed", OnSuccess = "feedbackRecorded", LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader-fb", UpdateTargetId = "newsletter", }, new { @id = "feedback" })) { %>
```

The first parameter to Ajax.BeginForm  that is the {action name} is now being marked in red color(I am using Resharper) and says that ‘cannot resolve action ‘ActionName’’, however the Action is present in my controller.

Another strange thing is that on running the app and submitting the form it ends up invoking the Javscript’s "OnSuccess” method as if it has succeeded but in actually nothing happened and it didn’t even get to first line call of the specified controllers action. (This is happening to both AJAX forms in the view)

Does anyone have any ideas about the possible reasons forit to behave this way suddenly?

Thankyou!

I just created a new 'SharedController' controller with the same action in it and now it is recognizing  but its is not recognizing in the UserController?

```
      public class SharedController : Controller
    {
            public ActionResult Feedback()
            {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Due to the brevity of the shown code I can only guess that you might have a form inside of a form.

Comment: I am having the same issue after I activated my resharper but my action actually works..it's just annoying to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `Ajax.BeginForm` is the controller name.

Try changing the code to:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Feedback", "Shared", ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Maven, about ReSharper - it's complaining right, because you use this method overload

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions,
    Object htmlAttributes)
```

where second parameter is routeValues, so ReSharper looks for action 'Feeeback' in current controller.

Obviously, you wanted another overload, with this invocation

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Feedback", "User", null, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode =  InsertionMode.InsertBefore, HttpMethod = "POST", OnFailure = "searchFailed", OnSuccess = "feedbackRecorded", LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader-fb", UpdateTargetId = "newsletter", }, new { @id = "feedback" })) { %>
```

Pay attention to third **null** argument.

Comment: Thank you this was driving me insane! I too "didn't see" the third argument. Doh!